# How to apply multiple filters to multiple value fields in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I use the following data...

[image: Sample Table]

...to create the following pivot table.

[image: Sample Pivot Table]

I want to apply the filter "FLORIDA SALES = Y" only to the first values column, and the filter "S.EAST SALES = Y" only to the second values column, to produce a pivot tables that looks like this:

[image]

I'm using colors here to show that I want each filter to filter only ONE of my value columns.  I have 16,592 distinct UPCs so choosing to filter based on UPC is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 2 new columns which will be populated via formula as follows:

1. "Florida Count" - `=if( B1 = "Y", 1, 0)` - where column B is "Florida Sales"
2. "SE Count" `=if( C1 = "Y", 1, 0)` - where column C is "S. East Sales"

Then you will use the pivot to sum these two new columns and you won't need any filtering.